# jquery mobile attribute data-autodividers

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

**LAST UPDATE**
The problem was that i needed the latest jquery mobile file.when i switched to 1.3 instead of the default 1.1.3 all was working fine.

**original question**

i have an MVC 4 project (demo project from ms to see MVC 4 and mobile devices adjustments).
in a view i have model which is a list of strings (speakers name).
i have the following code to load the speakers:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
    @foreach(var speaker in Model) {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(speaker, "SessionsBySpeaker", new { speaker })</li>
    }
</ul>
```

the thing here is the **data-autodividers="true"** which i expected to work  - doesn't.
i'm getting the list of speakers but without the first character divider.

Should i call refresh on the **ul** after the **foreach** is done ? 

If yes , how ? and if not what is the correct way to activate this attribute ?

Thanks Gilad

**UPDATE**

i have tried zyrex answer and added this code to the bottom of my view :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#spkrs").listview({
            autodividers: true
    });
        $('#spkrs').listview('refresh');
    });   
</script>
```

but no chnage with the outcome.any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an ID to your listview and then:

```
$("#mylistview").listview({
  autodividers: true;
});
```

and then refresh the listview:

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: it didn't change the outcome.am i missing something with my implementation of your answer ?

Comment: dont use document.ready ... use pageinit, go to jqmobile site and lookup how-to. add an semikolon after true; ..

Comment: Sorry but your answer might be true but the real problem was that i needed the latest jquery mobile file.when i switched to 1.3 instead of the default 1.1.3 all was working fine without the extra script.